# Link href in a pug template

Tags: node.js, templates, layout, pug

I am using pug as the view engine of a nodejs application. I have a layout that every other current view extends, that contains a navbar with links to common urls across the app.

For example, a link to the signin url would look like :

```
a(href='/auth/signin')`
```

This works fine from the root url ('/'), correctly leads to '/auth/signin'.

Within the '/auth' module which contains the routes for '/auth/signin', '/auth/signup' and '/auth/signout', the behavior is different. Instead, the route is concatenated with the current module's name. So for example, within the '/auth/signin' route, the link is actually a link to '/auth/auth/signin'. Clicking on it naturally leads to a 404, but on that page the link to signin is a link to '/auth/auth/auth/signin'.

And so on and so forth.

I don't fully understand what is going on here and how to prevent it. Is there away to link to my routes in absolute terms in pug without straight up typing the full url (which is unpractical for a variety of reasons), the same way you'd use a route helper in Ruby on Rails ?

Comment: If you start your href's with a slash then these are interpreted as absolute url's. Then it does not matter in which folder your pug file is located. Please check that your href's start with `/` always.

Comment: Wow, I was sure I tried that out already. Embarassing ! Thanks for the help, I was going crazy.

Comment: Glad to know you sorted it out :)

Answer (score 3):

Solution from the comments:

If you start your href's with a slash then these are interpreted as absolute url's. Then it does not matter in which folder your pug file is located. Please check that your href's start with / always.